# File upload issue in angular-Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I used to upload files by using angular and web api and it all works fine with below code. But when i tried to upload `.zip` files it failed with below error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'upload' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

The code used in angular is as below

```
public uploadFiles(fd) : Observable<any> {
    console.log('reached uploadFiles in networkinfo');
    var url = this.baseApiUrl + 'RadioLink/upload' ;

    return this.httpService.post(url , fd);
}//responseType: 'blob'
```

even i tried to add headers as below with no luck

```
   public uploadFiles(fd) : Observable<any> {
        console.log('reached uploadFiles in networkinfo');
        var url = this.baseApiUrl + 'RadioLink/upload' ;
        console.log('networkinfo url = '+url);
       // var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' });
        var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT',
          });
        //let obj = new SaveRequestForTranLink({ Action: a,BH_SLNO:bh_slNo, BHTransmissionLink: link, RequestProjectSearch: this.requestSearch});
        return this.httpService.post(url , fd);
    }//responseType: 'blob'
```

any idea how to fix issue

**EDIT**
Sorry,this seems file size issue ,when i tried to upload large .zip file ,this error comes.Small .zip files are working fine

Comment: CORS header should be added on server not on clientside. However you should get the error for all the file type not just zip only.

Comment: how at server side web api??any i am able to upload .csv,.xlsx ets except .zip now

Comment: Sorry,this seems file size issue ,when i tried to upload large .zip file ,this error comes.Small .zip files are working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry all,this was file size issue from angular to web api, after doing below changes in web api webconfig ,issue is fixed

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />

<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```